# VS17 Report Viewer not showing report

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2017

I am working with ASP.NET and C# to make a webpage in VS2017. I currently have a reportviewer control that refuses to show anything. I get no errors thrown, no squiggly underlines, just the top bar of the reportviewer itself and no report shown.
This is my ASP:

```
<asp:View ID="Print" runat="server">

        <center>
        <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="RV_Main" runat="server" Height="100px" SizeToReportContent="True">
        </rsweb:ReportViewer>


    </asp:View>
```

This is my C#:

```
var SQLString = "SELECT * FROM BobsTable ORDER BY Firstname, Lastname";


        #region Initialize Connection
        var Class_Connection = new SQL_Connection();
        var sql = new SQL_Statements();
        Class_Connection.cnn.Close();
        #endregion


        var cmd = new SqlCommand(SQLString, Class_Connection.cnn);

        var dt = new DataTable();

        Class_Connection.cnn.Open();

        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

        var source = new ReportDataSource("UncleBob", dt);

        RV_Main.Visible = true;
        RV_Main.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        RV_Main.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Directories/BobsReport.rdlc");
        RV_Main.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(source);
        RV_Main.LocalReport.Refresh();

        Class_Connection.cnn.Close();


        MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 2;
```

The Dataset on my Report.rdlc file is "UncleBob".
The TableAdapter i have in in the connection file is properly populated with all of the fields that the SQL above is trying to pull.

I have had someone more experienced than I take a look at it and they were unable to find a reason it is doing this. I have spent 4 hours digging through the internet looking for and attempting fixes and repairs(thank god for backups).

Edit: This is a new report in an existing webpage with other reports that all work perfectly in non-IE browsers(i test in firefox).

Comment: random things: is the report maybe partially hidden within its parent element? if you change the path to something that definitely doesn't exist, does it then break or does it do the same thing? is there definitely at least one row of data in your result set?

Comment: Something to try -- but I thought this had been fixed a year ago or more.  This exact symptom used to present when trying to use ReportViewer with non-IE browsers -- so if you are seeing in this Chrome or Firefox or whatever -- and have not tried IE (maybe with compatibility mode too) then you should at least try it.  It is an easy test.

Comment: Thank you  David Tansey for pointing out the IE issue. I have another report  on a diferent page in the project that was existing before i moved from vs15 to vs17. I will try when i get back to the office on monday but the existing report works in Firefox, so i would THINK that this new report should also.

Comment: Sahuagin, Yes, i have table with about 50 entries that i am using for this report. If i change to a report that i not there the viewer breaks. however i am not quite sure what you mean about "hidden within it's parent element"

David Tansey, I tested in IE this morning when i got to work and it does the exact same thing as in Firefox.

Comment: I have not figured out what the issue was with this problem. for the sake of productivity i decided to drop the issue and throw the report into a report viewer that was working and continue with my work.